# Changing default constructor to parameterized

Tags: c++

I had a class "SetupModel" with default constructor. Now I have to include one parameter to this constructor. So it should be as,

```
class SetupModel
{
public:
   SetupModel(MyData::ValueSystem& valueSystem);
```

So I am trying to change all references of this class SetupModel.

But in another one class this has been called as,

```
class  SetupManager
{
 private:
   SetupModel _model;
```

am getting error "no appropriate default constructor available"

How can I change this?

Comment: You can have multiple constructors if the non parameterised way of creating the `SetupModel` object is not going to create problems

Comment: Either keep the default constructor (or make a defaulted default constructor) while adding the parameterized constructor. Or use a *constructor initializer list* to construct the member variable correctly.

Comment: Change constructor declaration to `SetupModel(const MyData::ValueSystem& valueSystem);` unless there is a requirement of write access of `valueSystem`

Answer (score 6):

```
class  SetupManager
{
  SetupManager(...) : _model(valuesystemarg), ...
  {
     ...
  }
 private:
   SetupModel _model;
```

Use initializer list to initialize this member.

Or add the default parameterless constructor to `SetupModel` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

add a definition of default constructor

```
class SetupModel
{
public:
   SetupModel(MyData::ValueSystem& valueSystem);
   SetupModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options in hand

1. If you prefer to use default constructor without parameters to be used during 
   construction of `SetupManager` you can define one more constructor within `SetupModel` without parameters

```
class SetupModel
{
public:
   SetupModel(MyData::ValueSystem& valueSystem);
   SetupModel() {};
```

So you don't need to make change in  `SetupManager`.

2. If you prefer to use `SetupModel` constructor with parameters as base class constructor of `SetupManager`, you can use initialization list within constructor of  `SetupManager`. Then you dont need further change in `SetupModel`

```
class  SetupManager
{
    SetupManager(...) : _model(valuesystemarg), ...
    {
       ...
    }
private:
     SetupModel _model;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many constructors as you want but if what you want is to have only one then you can set the default value both in .h or in .cpp

in .h:

```
class  SetupManager
{
    SetupManager() : _model(value), // here you can set all variables u want    separated by a coma

   private:
     SetupModel _model;
}
```

in cpp:

```
SetupManager::SetupManager():
{
   _model = value;
}
```

Be careful so in .h the value is inside "(" and ")" while in cpp you use "=" to assign the value